# Aggregate columns values by string column numerated name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table

[image]

I want to sum values of the columns beloning to the same class h.*. So, my final table will look like this:

[image]

Is it possible to aggregate by string column name?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you please share a sample of the data, not an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function first for select first 3 characters with parameter `axis=1` or indexing columns names similar way and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('object')

df2 = df1.groupby(lambda x: x[:3], axis=1).sum().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.set_index('object')

df2 = df1.groupby(df1.columns.str[:3], axis=1).sum().reset_index()
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

cols = ['object', 'h.1.1','h.1.2','h.1.3','h.1.4','h.1.5',
        'h.2.1','h.2.2','h.2.3','h.2.4','h.3.1','h.3.2','h.3.3']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 13)), columns=cols)
print (df)
   object  h.1.1  h.1.2  h.1.3  h.1.4  h.1.5  h.2.1  h.2.2  h.2.3  h.2.4  \
0       2      2      6      1      3      9      6      1      0      1   
1       9      3      4      0      0      4      1      7      3      2   
2       4      8      0      7      9      3      4      6      1      5   
3       8      3      5      0      2      6      2      4      4      6   

   h.3.1  h.3.2  h.3.3  
0      9      0      0  
1      4      7      2  
2      6      2      1  
3      3      0      6 

df1 = df.set_index('object')
df2 = df1.groupby(lambda x: x[:3], axis=1).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
   object  h.1  h.2  h.3
0       2   21    8    9
1       9   11   13   13
2       4   27   16    9
3       8   16   16    9
```

Comment: @hacker315 - For you not?

Comment: I thought x[:3] takes only the first 3 columns only and I couldn't understand the grouping on it..

Comment: @hacker315 - no, because `, axis=1` - it use first letter from columns names.

Comment: @hacker315 - Sample special created for you :)

Comment: @jezrael, both solutions working perfectly! Sorry for responding only now. This is so simple but I would never come to this by myself :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The solution above works great, but is vulnerable in case the h.X goes beyond single digits. I'd recommend the following:

**Sample Data:**

```
cols = ['h.%d.%d' %(i, j) for i in range(1, 11) for j in range(1, 11)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, len(cols))), columns=cols, index=['p_%d'%p for p in range(4)])
```

**Proposed Solution:**

```
new_df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[1], axis=1).sum()
new_df.columns = 'h.' + new_df.columns # the columns are originallly numbered 1, 2, 3. This brings it back to h.1, h.2, h.3
```

**Alternative Solution:**

Going through multiindices might be more convoluted, but may be useful while manipulating this data elsewhere.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True) # Transform into a multiindex
new_df = df.sum(axis = 1, level=[0,1])
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.get_level_values(0) + '.' + new_df.columns.get_level_values(1) # Rename columns
```

Comment: thank you for your solutions. They are working,  Awesome! :)